# How to fire JavaScript function when autoComplete is popup?

Tags: asp.net, autocomplete

I use `asp:AutoCompleteExtender` control in my page.

Here is control:

```
 <asp:AutoCompleteExtender ID="txtStreet_AutoCompleteExtender" runat="server" DelimiterCharacters=""
        Enabled="True" MinimumPrefixLength="2" ServiceMethod="GetCompletionList"  ServicePath=""
        TargetControlID="txtStreet">
    </asp:AutoCompleteExtender>
```

I also have javascript function named `sizeCalc(autoCompleteHeight)` the function has parameter named `autoCompleteHeight` that get height of the `autoComplete` popup.

My question is how can  fire sizeCalc function when autoComplete popup appears  and pass the height of the autoComplete popup window?

Answer (score 0):

here it's getting fired for a MinimumPrefixLength so we're gonna check based on that.

This is using jQuery assuming it's a normal textbox or you'll need to give your server control a clientID attribute.

```
$('#txtStreet').keyup(function() {
    if(this.value.length > 2)
{
  //your code
}
});
```